# show loading before load page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#wrapper').load('page.php');
    });
});
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<div id="button">click me</div>
```

I want show loading before send (load) `page.php` after click `#button`

Comment: how do you send load!! I cannot see any event that send load in your question,,

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {` should be outside the button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the jsfiddle script https://jsfiddle.net/1uwopptv/ or inline script assuming this is what you want. You can again hide the loading gif, after request is completed.

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#img').show(); 
    $('#button').hide(); 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#wrapper').load('page.php');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<div id="button">click me</div>
<img src="https://loading.io/assets/img/landing/curved-bars.svg" id="img" style="display:none"/ >
```

`Disclaimer` : Image used belongs to site loading.io, as came up in first google search.